# Key pool in wallet softwares

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, multibit, electrum, keypool

From my understanding, bitcoind/bitcoin-qt uses a key pool for their wallet, so when you create a wallet you are actually creating not just one but many addresses for sending/receiving transactions.

How about multibit or electrum? Do they also use a key pool? What are the advantages and disadvantages of using a key pool vs. using a single address for the wallet?

Comment: related question: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/8825/5406

Answer (score 3):

*Bitcoin-QT with standard settings will keep 100 unused addresses in your wallet at all times. The goal is that backups will be future proof to some extent.*

### A key pool allows to create backups in bigger intervals

Every time you create a transaction, the remainder of the input balance is sent to a new address in your own wallet. If addresses were generated only then, you would have to create a new backup after each transaction, or be at risk to lose any funds associated with that new address if your wallet got lost. By keeping a pool of unused addresses in store, your backup will be sufficient for the next 100 transactions before you will be at risk of losing something.

To create a bigger key pool, with e.g. 10000 keys, the client can be started with the parameter `-keypool=10000`.

I don't have intimate knowledge of either multibit or electrum, but suspect that they keep a key pool for the exact same reason.

### One vs. many addresses

Using **many addresses**, i.e. a new address for each transaction,

- increases your privacy by making it harder to determine that your different transactions belong to the same person.
- obfuscate which part of your transaction went to the recipient and which was the change.
- create *plausible deniability* as sending funds to yourself looks the same as sending to another user.
- By giving out a new address for each incoming payment, it is easier associate payments to specific senders. *Say, you go out with a three business partners and each ends up owing you 0.10 BTC. How would you know who paid already, if you only received two payments to the same address?*

Using only **one address**

- allows your backup to last forever
- reduces the overhead if people send funds to you more than once.
- Your privacy, and the privacy of your business partners might be reduced.

Answer (score 3):

> How about multibit or electrum? Do they also use a key pool?

Electrum is deterministic and addresses are derived from your seed. Each time you need a new address, Electrum calculates it and shows it in the client.

Being deterministic lets Electrum **recover your entire wallet addresses from your seed**, so you don't need to backup your wallet file every time you make a transaction.